# Design pattern to ensure do something & write database success

Tags: design-patterns

Assuming I want to build a cinema aggregator app, I have a transaction database. I want to save the state after the customer makes a booking.

So the flow will be like,
init the data, make a book to my supplier by HTTP call, then update the data in the database

if the HTTP call is a success, it's ok, but the problem is when the HTTP call succeeds but the app fails to update the transaction status in the database.

is there any design pattern to use, to make sure the update operation is success when the HTTP call is success?

Answer (score 0):

About all you can do is to minimize the window of time in where this can happen. One pattern is to begin a transaction before making the HTTP call and commit it after, or write to the database before the HTTP, and update it after to record that the HTTP call was successful.